# Headless browsers use with Youtube

Tags: python, youtube

I am trying to automate a task I want to perform on YouTube. I need to search and play Youtube videos then play the "up next" video and so forth without actually playing them. I need to trick YouTube that the entire video was played while hiding my ip if possible.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I would use Selenium if you’re not already. Import options as well and add - - headless to the argument.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
chrome_options = Options()
#chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
#chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
driver =    webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)

start_url = "https://google.com"
driver.get(start_url)
print(driver.page_source.encode("utf-8"))
driver.quit()
```